# ¿Cómo pasar ciertos strings de una sublista a otra lista?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, bucle-for

Tengo `letters`, la cual tiene varias sublistas, y tengo `max`.

Lo que ando intentando hacer es llenar una nueva lista `stringWithMax` con las sublistas de `letters`, pero que de manera que las sublistas solo se tome el valor desde el indice `1` hasta el índice que tiene `max` en su posición `i`.
Por ejemplo, quiero llenar `stringWithMax[0]` con `letters[0]` pero quiero que de `letters[0]` solo se tomen los valores que tienen índice en el rango de [1, max[0]), de manera que al imprimir  `stringWithMax` sus datos en consola sean `[['a', 'c', 'b']]`, luego llenar `stringWithMax[1]` con los datos de `letters[1]` pero que solo se tomen los valores en el rango de [1, max[1]) para que al imprimir `stringWithMax` los datos en consola sean `[['a', 'c', 'b'], ['F', 'P', 'Z', 'W']]`, y así sucesivamente con las otras líneas, para que al final al imprimir `stringWithMax` ya de manera final, su contenido total sea `[['a', 'c', 'b'], ['F', 'P', 'Z', 'W'], ['R', 'X', 'N']]`.
La parte de los rangos puede que la haya planteado mal, mas sin embargo se entiende la salida que quiero.

Lo que he intentado es esto:

```
letters = [['letters1', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'BUILD'], ['letter2','F', 'P', 'Z', 'W', 'SHOW', 'BUILD'], ['leters3','R', 'X', 'N', 'BUILD', 'SHOW']]
max = [4, 5, 4]

stringWithMax = []
def  reGet():
    for i in range(len(letters)):
        for x in range(1, max[i]): 
            stringWithMax.append(letters[i][x])
    print(stringWithMax)

reGet()
```

Con esto la salida en consola es `['a', 'c', 'b', 'F', 'P', 'Z', 'W', 'R', 'X', 'N']`, lo cual es parecido a lo que quiero que como digo arriba es de tal forma`[['a', 'c', 'b'], ['F', 'P', 'Z', 'W'], ['R', 'X', 'N']]`, solamente que le hace falta dividirlo en sublistas.

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar, gracias!

Answer (score 1):

solo te falta un par de detalles en tu codigo:

```
letters = [['letters1', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'BUILD'], ['letter2','F', 'P', 'Z', 'W', 'SHOW', 'BUILD'], ['leters3','R', 'X', 'N', 'BUILD', 'SHOW']]
max = [4, 5, 4]

stringWithMax = []
def  reGet():
    for i in range(len(letters)):
```

hasta acá bien, pero ahora hay que agregar una lista  vacía por cada fila

```
         stringWithMax.append([])
```

listo, ahora lo que falta:

```
    for x in range(1, max[i]): 
            stringWithMax[i].append(letters[i][x])
```

agregamos los valores a la lista nueva

otra cosa, no es que esté mal, pero es mejor que la función retorne la lista en vez de mostrarla

```
    return stringWithMax
```

en definitiva todo el código para que se entienda

```
letters = [['letters1', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'BUILD'], ['letter2','F', 'P', 'Z', 'W', 'SHOW', 'BUILD'], ['leters3','R', 'X', 'N', 'BUILD', 'SHOW']]
max = [4, 5, 4]

stringWithMax = []
def  reGet():
    for i in range(len(letters)):
        stringWithMax.append([])
        for x in range(1, max[i]): 
            stringWithMax[i].append(letters[i][x])
    return stringWithMax

print(reGet())
```

toda esta chorrada de explicación es para los que patalean por las respuestas simplificadas.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer eso que quieres con:

```
letters = [['letters1', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'BUILD'], ['letter2','F', 'P', 'Z', 'W', 'SHOW', 'BUILD'], ['leters3','R', 'X', 'N', 'BUILD', 'SHOW']]
max = [4, 5, 4]

print([l[1:max[i]] for i,l in enumerate(letters)])
```

Devuelve:

```
[['a', 'c', 'b'], ['F', 'P', 'Z', 'W'], ['R', 'X', 'N']]
```